# Sphinx returns totally wrong count() result

Tags: count, sphinx

The problem is the following. I've got index which MySQL source contains 4.5M+ entries.
But count() query shows only 1.5M+ entries in this index. Please see details:

When I run indexer for this source I see:

```
# indexer --rotate <index>

Sphinx 2.2.2-id64-beta (r4553)
Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc ( http://sphinxsearch.com )

using config file '/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index '<index>'...
collected 4558763 docs, 552.5 MB
sorted 81.7 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 4558763 docs, 552512903 bytes
total 889.631 sec, 621058 bytes/sec, 5124.32 docs/sec
total 4561032 reads, 14.043 sec, 0.4 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 5991 writes, 13.257 sec, 498.2 kb/call avg, 2.2 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=29227).
```

It says that "collected *4558763* docs, 552.5 MB".

On the other hand when I run count query I get this:

```
sphinxQL> select * from <index> limit 0; show meta;
Empty set (0.14 sec)

+---------------+---------+
| Variable_name | Value   |
+---------------+---------+
| total         | 1000    |
| total_found   | 1570351 |
| time          | 0.072   |
+---------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or this query (same result):

```
sphinxQL> select 1 as d, count(*) c from <index> group by d;
+------+---------+
| d | c |
+------+---------+
| 1 | 1570351 |
+------+---------+
1 row in set (0.15 sec)
```

So it looks like sphinx found only **1.5M+** entries. How it's possible? Maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can search "max_matches" parameter in your sphinx.conf, it can be setted there.
2. Add to query "OPTION" string. Query would be like this:

   select * from  limit 0 OPTION max_matches=10000000

Try both this ideas.